# Can't browse consul ui when running on vagrant (from consul tutorial)

Tags: vagrant, consul

I ran consul cluster using [vagrant file](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/demo/vagrant-cluster/Vagrantfile) from the tutorial.

I added the first machine 'forwarded_port' attribute so now it looks like this

```
config.vm.define "n1" do |n1|
      n1.vm.hostname = "n1"
      n1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.20.20.10"
      n1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8500, host: 8500
end
```

In order to view the UI from the host I added -ui and -client attribute to run as follows:

```
consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent-one   
-bind=172.20.20.10 -enable-script-checks=true -config-dir=/etc/consul.d  
-ui -client=172.20.20.10
```

I can curl  'http://172.20.20.10:8500/ui/' from the guest and the host.
but when I try to join

consul join 172.20.20.11

I get

```
Error joining address '172.20.20.11': Put 
http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/join/172.20.20.11: dial tcp 
127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused . 
Failed to join any nodes.
```

How can I join the cluster when using client attribute?
(Alternatively, how can I see the ui from the host?) .

Answer (score 0):

I've ran a separate agent to run the ui with the following command after starting the server node separately.

```
consul agent -ui -bind=172.20.20.11 -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent-two -config-dir=/etc/consul.d -client=0.0.0.0
```

After that, I've joined the cluster using

```
consul join 172.20.20.10
```

I guess, the difference is separating the server node and ui node.